# Unable to scroll linear layout inside a horizontal scrollview in android

Tags: android

I am adding few image views inside a horizontal LinearLayout which is again inside a HorizontalScrollView. But the linear layout is not scrolling. Below is my code. Can someone guide me where exactly my xml formation is going wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <HorizontalScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lyt_items"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_icon1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/default_ic" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_icon2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/default_ic"  />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_icon3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/default_ic" />

                    </LinearLayout>
     </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: The `LinearLayout`'s `layout_width` should be `wrap_content`, not `match_parent`.

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: If the `ImageView`s' total width isn't larger than the `HorizontalScrollView`'s, it's not going to scroll. If you're sure it is, then it would seem that there's issues stemming from the rest of the layout.

Comment: Yes, it is larger. I can see a portion of the last image in the Horizontal ScrollView but it isn't scrolling

Comment: I have removed everything now, and have put the above xml inside a relative parent layout. Still no luck

Comment: Your code perfectly works for me

Comment: test case: make first imageview width to 250 dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest use **Constraint Layout** As Parent and Inside it Use **Nested Scroll View** With Linear Layout

> Here is a sample code, modify according to your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="suraj.iitgandhinagar.Login">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="72dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="36dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="272dp"
                android:layout_height="237dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/unnamed"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If i use nested scrollview, then the last visible image becomes extremely small

Comment: Try to use `android:layout_marginBottom` on the last Image and remove padding from the image if any.

Comment: I think is that, i have  9 images out of which if i put my linear layout inside a scrollview or nested scrollview only 7 are being seen and the 7th one dimension is getting half of the rest 6

Comment: And there is no scrolling

Comment: Atleast if i use Horizontal scrollview, the 7th image doesnt get shrinked in size

Comment: Then you can try using Relative layout inside Linear Layout & I expect that the code provided above you changed `android:orientation="Horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this situation. if you use the linear layout as `match_parent` then don't get the layout width. Use `wrap_content`. If its don't work then set the fixed size for your image.

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```